# Passing item clicked from list while adding new data to RavenDB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I'm using ASP.NET MVC framework and RavenDB to develop a website for restaurants to take reservations and orders online.

In the admin site, the admin is able to add restaurant. After restaurant is added, the admin can click 'Add Menu' to navigate to the add menu page (as shown below)
[image]

However, when the menu is added, the restaurant name is not being saved to the DB.
[image]

In RavenDB,

```
{
    "foodItemCode": "A01",
    "foodItemName": "Butter & Spice Chicken Chop",
    "price": 16,
    "description": null
}
```

How can I pass the restaurant name clicked from the restaurantList while saving the data of menu to DB?

Sorry if this question sounds dumb to anyone but I'm need a beginner so please bear with me while I am putting effort to learn more :)

**EDIT**

RestaurantMenu.cs - model for AddMenu.cshtml

```
public class RestaurantMenu
    {
        public string restaurantName { get; set; }
        public string foodItemCode { get; set; }
        public string foodItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

AddMenu.cshtml

```
@model Foodfury.Models.Restaurant
<div class="addMenu">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddMenu", "Admin", method: FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ui form" }))
    {
       <div class="field">
          <label>Restaurant</label>
          <input type="text" name="model.restaurantName" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RestaurantName)" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Food code (Optional)</label>
            <input class="ui input" type="text" name="model.foodItemCode" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Food Name</label>
            <input class="ui input" type="text" name="model.foodItemName" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input class="ui input" type="text" name="model.description" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input class="ui input" type="number" name="model.price" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui buttons">
            <button class="ui button">Cancel</button>
            <div class="or"></div>
            <button class="ui positive button" type="submit" id="btnAddMenu">Add to menu</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

[image: What I want is the input field for Restaurant displayed the restaurant name clicked in previous page (RestaurantList).]
I'm not sure what am I doing wrong in order to pass the restaurant name clicked when inserting new menu.

In my controller,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddMenu(RestaurantMenu model)
    {
        using (var store = new DocumentStore
        {
            Url = "http://localhost:8080/",
            DefaultDatabase = "foodfurydb"
        })
        {
            store.Initialize();

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(model);
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You need to post some more relevant code, or at least describe how it works already a bit more. The best guess from what you describe is that you are not posting the restaurant data back to the server before attempting to add a menu

Comment: @ste-fu sorry, added the code above :)

Comment: Your model does not contain any properties for the restaurant name, and you have not shown the relevant code where you pass the restaurant name to the second view.

Comment: I just updated the code again. Mind to have a look again? Thanks